# How to generate JSON from table using AngularJs for saving tabular data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have create one HTML with the help of AngularJS.

```
<form name="target" ng-submit="createAllKeywordsJSON(codeMasterList)"><!-- createAllKeywordsJSON() -->
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="myButton" name="submit" style="margin: 0px;float:right;">

    <div class="category-placer2" style="width:100%">
      <div class="category-header-keywords">
        <div class="icon-add"><a href="#"><img src="images/icon-add.png" alt="Add" border="0" title="Add phone Number" /></a></div>
        <div class="category-header-text" ><span ng-bind="dispName"></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="category-base">
        <div class="keywordplacer">

            <table width="99%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="keywordsList">
                <tr>                
                    <th width="60%" colspan="2">Code Master Name</th>
                    <th width="30%" colspan="2">Status</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="type in codeMasterList">
                    <td width="1%" class="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="codeMasterId" value="{{type.codeMasterId}}" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="60%" class="">
                        <input type="text" name="keywordName" value="{{type.name}}" alt="Name of Keyword" size="60" >
                    </td>
                    <td width="30%" class="">
                        <input type="radio" value="1" name="{{type.codeMasterId}}" alt="Name of Keyword" ng-checked="{{(type.activeInd == 1) && ('true') || ('false')}}" />Active
                        <input type="radio" value="0" name="{{type.codeMasterId}}" alt="Name of Keyword" ng-checked="{{(type.activeInd == 0) && ('true') || ('false')}}" style="margin-left:50px;" />Inactive
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <center>
            <hr style=" background-color: #ABBFC6; height: 2px; width: 90%;">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="myButton" style="margin: 0px;"/>
        </center>
        <!-- <div class="table-index">P - Primary</div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It will show value in editable mode.

I want to save all the list at a single click on save button. how can i do such thing using angularjs ?

Can you please help me to generate JSON data for the name as well as for radio button value ?

below is my controller:

```
keywordModule.controller('keywordTypeController',['$scope', '$http', 'keywordService',
    function($scope, $http, keywordService) {
        $scope.createAllKeywordsJSON = function() {
            //alert($scope.codeMasterList.codeMasterId);
            var tempItemList = [];
            angular.foreach($scope.codeMasterList,function(item,index){
                tempItemList.push(item);
            });
            alert(tempItemList);
            /*keywordService.createAllKeywordsJSON().query(codeMasterList,
                    //Success Handler handler
                    function(data) {

                    },
                    //Failure handler
                    function(error) {

                    }
            );*/
            //alert(codeMasterList);
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$scope.codeMasterList` would be the `JSON` data for your list.

You can update the value of the form fields by using `ng-model` instead of `value`.  This also will bind the input values right back to the item in the list.  So then you can just save `$scope.codeMasterList`

*HTML Sample*

```
<input type="text" ng-model="type.name" alt="Name of Keyword" size="60" >
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/L78kfkx8/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to pass that latest {{ mylist }} to the controller, so that I can pass it to the service and save it through hibernate so can you please help me to pass that to controller after submitting the form? you can help me to http://jsfiddle.net/L78kfkx8/3

Comment: [this is what I would do](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/L78kfkx8/4/), you do not need to pass a reference to get the list to the controller.

Comment: If you want to strip the angular `ng-repeat` `$$hashkey` then do an `angular.copy($scope.myList)`

Comment: its working fine in JSFiddle, but when I am trying same into real code , its shows me error ": angular.foreach is not a function", can you please help me?

Comment: I'm not sure why you changed my fiddle, you do not need the `angular.forEach()` I updated the fiddle again please take a look, you are adding a lot of extra code to the `ng-checked` and `$scope.ok` functions you do not need.